# How can I treat items in an expl3 clist as sequences?

Tags: expl3, package-writing, latex3, xparse, comma-separated-list

According to my lights, the following code should typeset `212`. However, my lights are obviously on the dark side as I actually get `111`. How can I change the code to work as expected?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \mylist {m}
{
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { : } { ##1 }
    \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\mylist{tikz:something,somethingelse,tikz:thirdthing}
\end{document}
```

The purpose of this is to process a sequence of images with potentially different options. For example,

```
\mylist{tikz:first-tikz-input,{graphics={width=.2\textwidth},rotate=30}:example-image-a,tikz:second-tikz-input}
```

I've tried using `\clist_map_variable:` instead of `\clist_map_inline:`. I've also tried generating `\seq_set_split:Nno` and `\seq_set_split:Nnx`, but whatever I try, the items stubbornly refuse to be split at the `:` delimiters.

[Can I store sequences in sequences with expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115700/can-i-store-sequences-in-sequences-with-expl3) suggests this may not be possible directly (if nesting sequences in comma-separated lists is relevantly like nesting them in sequences). However, the descriptions in the documentation suggest that nesting them should now be possible, so I'm not sure if those answers are current.

Comment: I think the problem is really the `:` which has a special meaning in `expl3`, that's why I use `/` or `!` in such cases

Comment: This could be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302387/real-colons-in-a-expl3-context

Comment: egreg will frown on the 'ineffectiveness' of `\clist_map_inline`, but using `\seq_set_from_clist:Nn` may be too much...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm such an idiot. Of course, you are surely right. I'm so used to `:` being a safe splitter in Forest/Ti*k*Z, but, of course, it can't be here. Although the documentation does not mention this ....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why is it 'ineffective'?

Comment: I think it's the internal storage mechanism/representation of the `\seq` variable compared to the `\clist` - type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a crude by-pass, generating a variant of `\seq_set_split:Nnn` with `NVn` that explicitly uses `V` as value expansion of the delimiter `\c_colon_str` in order to force a literal `:` there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NVn,cVn}
\NewDocumentCommand \mylist {m}
{
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} {
    \seq_set_split:NVn \l_tmpa_seq { \c_colon_str } { ##1 }
    \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\mylist{tikz:something,somethingelse,tikz:thirdthing}
\end{document}
```

The output is `212` there, i.e. 2 items for the first, 1 item for 2nd and 2 items for 3rd 'seq' again.

Comment: Actually, I've just changed `:` to `|`. But you definitely deserve the tick!

Comment: @cfr: Yes, as I wrote in a comment above: I use `/` or `!` or have a code where the separator is stored in `\prop` list before, which is used as string then

Comment: Oh, you understand the `\prop` stuff ;). Good for you. (I don't.)

Comment: @cfr: `\prop` is one of my favourite concepts of `expl3`.

Comment: Hmm ... maybe I should read that bit of the manual. What is it for?

Comment: @cfr: Think of `\prop` variables as hashes or as the `expl3` approach of `arrays`.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't actually help much but the idea of an array does mean something to me.